# I'm getting an empty response even before action returns in Struts

Tags: ajax, struts2

I'm getting an empty response when I do an ajax call with a particular set of parameters (works fine in other cases). The thing that is baffling me is that I get that empty response even before my action has returned.
I can see an error in my firebug console even when my netbeans debugger has just entered the action class.
I'm clueless any pointers?

Comment: How are you making the Ajax call? Are you sure you're looking for the right status/event/callback afterwards?

Comment: What are those particular set of parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you are monitoring the ready state of any AJAX calls, such as the following:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
       document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
}
```